# Zend Framework 1 > OK, I've written a custom validator. Where do I put it? How does my Zend_Form include it?

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

I've written my own Zend framework custom validator. But the documentation seems to fall short of telling my 1) where to save it, and 2) how to include it in my Zend_Form. Is there no such convention in Zend? Can anyone advise:

Here is my custom validator class. I'm not sure if this is correct convention but I've put it within my library/QA folder as I can autoload everything there with composer autoload:

```
<?php

class QA_Validators_TagRange extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    ...
}
```

Next, I have a file form/questionsForm.php with the following class:

```
<?php

class QuestionForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->addElement('text', 'tags', array(
            'label'      => 'Tags',
            'required'   => true,
            'filters' => array(
                'StringTrim',
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                'NotEmpty'
            )
        ));

        ...
    }
}
```

How does my new custom validator fit within this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you could do it in 2 ways,

```
$yourValidator = new QA_Validators_TagRange();  
$yourField->addValidator($yourValidator, true);
```

This should look under `library\QA\Validator\TagRange.php`

OR

```
$yourField->addPrefixPath('QA_Validators', 'QA/Validators/', 'validate');        
$yourField->addValidator('TagRange', true);
```

This should look under `library\QA\Validator\TagRange.php`

**Update**
You can also add validators in the style you added in your question, as:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'tags', array(
    'label'      => 'Tags',
    'required'   => true,
    'filters' => array(
        'StringTrim',
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array('TagRange', true, array(
            'messages' => array(….)  
     ))
    )
));
```

But for this style of adding validators, i think you need to set

[$form->addElementPrefixPaths($elementPrefixPaths);](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Form/Zend_Form.html#addElementPrefixPaths) . I think `addValidator()` way is much easier

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I can get it working now. However, is it possible to use a custom validator in the style I've used above where filter, validators etc are passed as options to `$this->addElement(..)`. If not, I'll update all my forms to your suggested approach just to keep things consistent. Is that a better approach anyway? (`$myfield = new ...; $myfield->addValidator(...); $myfield->addFilter(...); $form->addElement($myfield)` etc) I can see the documentation gives examples in that manner, however I find $this->addElement(array(...)) encapsulates everything a little tidier. Just a thought.

Comment: @user3265472 Yes you could also add validators within addElement, but personally i feel its much easier to use addValidator() method, as it can be used without much trouble..